# cURL Settings Prevent Authentication to Yahoo Caldav Server

Tags: curl, yahoo, caldav

Im not sure the title of this question is what it actually asks for, i am using a PHP Library https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV for connecting to different Calendar providers, Like Owncloud, iCloud, Yahoo, etc, iam able to connect, list calendars and get the events from these three providers, now the problem is with yahoo only, when i run this file on my server yahoo does not return the calendars list, but it works on localhost/

yahoo caldav ur is url : `https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/username/Calendar/calendar_name/`

i updated php and cURL to same versions on both , that didnt make any difference
 but i found some configuration changes for cURL on local and server as below

**Server**

- GSS-Negotiate No
- SPNEGO Yes
- TLS-SRP No

**Local**

- GSS-Negotiate YES
- SPNEGO No
- TLS-SRP YES

all except these value are same, i cant figure out where it goes wrong

**EDIT**

```
$client->connect('https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/userXXX/Calendar/', 'xxx@yahoo.com', 'paswordXXX');

 $arrayOfCalendars = $client->findCalendars(); // Returns an array of all accessible calendars on the server.

    foreach( $arrayOfCalendars as $cal) {
        echo $cal->getCalendarID();
    }
```

Comment: The calendar homeset would be https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/username/Calendar/, not https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/username/Calendar/calendar_name/. Why do you think authentication is failing? Any logs etc?

Comment: it works on localhost, but not in server, see the cURL difference i posted with question, that only i know

Comment: What exactly does Yahoo return? Please post the request that you send and the server response.

Comment: @hnh, with that url , it is listing all the calendars in my yahoo, problem is with AWS server only, works perfectly on localserver

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: CalDAVClient::$xmltags in /usr/share/nginx/html/.....

Comment: function HrefValueInside($tagname) {
        foreach ($this->xmltags[$tagname] AS $k => $v) {
            $j = $v + 1;
            if ($this->xmlnodes[$j]['tag'] == 'DAV::href') {
                return rawurldecode($this->xmlnodes[$j]['value']);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Discussion is here http://lists.calconnect.org/pipermail/caldeveloper-l/2015-January/000803.html